# How to save pdf file in node js with express and multer

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I'm using a multer api, and I'm saving files in memory, because I need to upload images and pdf, and I need to process the images.

I can upload images, but I can't upload pdfs files.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

well, this is my code... I really hope to help you.

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const app = express();

const storage =
    multer.diskStorage({
    destination: path.join(__dirname, 'public/img/'), // destination folder
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, uuid.v4() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
});

const upload =
multer({
storage,
dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public/img/'), // destination folder
limits: {fileSize: 3500000}, // size we will acept, not bigger
fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    const filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|gif|pdf/; // filetypes you will accept
    const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype); // verify file is == filetypes you will accept
    const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname)); // extract the file extension
    // if mimetype && extname are true, then no error
    if(mimetype && extname){
        return cb(null, true);
    }
    // if mimetype or extname false, give an error of compatibilty
    return cb("The uploaded file, isn't compatible :( we're sorry");
}
}).single('image'); // This is the field where is the input type="file", we only accept 1 image
app.use(upload);
```

and the view will looks like this

```
app.post('/add', async (req, res) => {
const { originalname, mimetype, destination, filename, path, size} = req.file;
const newImage = {
    originalname,
    mimetype,
    destination,
    filename,
    path,
    size
};
await pool.query('Insert Into imagen set ?', [newImage]);
res.send('image uploaded');
});
```

Comment: What pool query do?

Comment: oh, i'm so sorry, i forgot to add that code... That runs the query, i will add this lately, i'm not with my pc here:(. const newImage's fields, are the columns in the database's table. E.g. mydb.image(originalname, mimetype...)

Answer (score 1):

this might help you

```
// Set storage engine
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: "./uploads",
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    // null as first argument means no error
    cb(null, Date.now() + "-" + file.originalname);
  },
});



  let encode_file = null;
  let fileName = "";
  if (req.file) {
    fileName = req.file.originalname;
    var filepath = path.join(__dirname, req.file.path);
    console.log(filepath);
    var stream = fs.readFileSync(filepath);
    encode_file = stream.toString("base64");
  }
```

Comment: In this way, I can upload files, PDF and img,.

Comment: But, I wanna process images before save

Comment: Can I please know, what Image processing you want to perform so that I can think about that..